# use numpy to add a column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have trying to add a column D to below df and add condition like this: if column C is in Shanghai, then D is Asia, if column C is SFA, then D is America...take these two as an example, my code as following:

```
  A     B   C      
0 Joe   23   SFA
1 Amy   40   SFA
2 Jenny 34   SFA
3 Kitty  20  Shanghai
4 David  19  Shanghai
...
```

code:

```
df['D'] = np.where(
    df['C'] == 'SFA','America',
    np.where(df['C'] =='Shnaghai','Asia','Other'
    )
)
```

But it keeps giving an error showing: KeyError:'C'
I have no idea why it give me this error always as I am pretty sure the data frame is pandas and the column C is being converted to string. Can anyone provide me any insights?

Comment: It looks like you have the code for conditional creation column correct, but the column name has some spaces in it. You can verify that is the issue by printing out `df.columns.tolist()`. You can fix the issue using `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`.

Comment: it gives me the same error after I doing these. When I apply the first formula, it doesn't return column C, but another one that I don't need.

Comment: What does `print(df.columns.tolist())` return, please copy-paste it here.

Comment: it returns another column ['Amount'] which I didn't post in this dataframe, I don't need this column for now.

Comment: So it returns [A, B, C, Amount]? Can you paste the output here?

Comment: It doesn't return any dataframe, just the column name: ['Amount']. Nothing else.

Comment: So you are trying to access column names that don't exist, don't you see the issue there?

Comment: If these are in fact levels in the index and not actual column names, you should reset the index first: `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: I am pretty sure all the columns are in the dataframe, they appear the exact names I put in the code and they are not in the index level.

Comment: In that case it should be reflected in the output of `print(df.columns.tolist())` At this point we are just talking in circles, so without more context I'm afraid your issue is not reproducible for anyone here, sorry.